# How to enqueue a job in sidekiq with Java or Scala

Tags: ruby, scala, resque, sidekiq, jesque

I have a sidekiq installation in ruby running, and I would like to enqueue jobs from a Scala / Java system. How can I do this? Here is my worker:

```
class MyWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform(param)
      puts "processing #{param}"
      # ...
    end
end
```

I tried to use [jesque](https://github.com/gresrun/jesque), but it is not working. Here is the jesque code I am trying to use:

```
val config = new ConfigBuilder().build();

val job = new Job("MyWorker", Array("my param"))
val client = new ClientImpl(config);
client.enqueue("default", job);
client.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the same namespace in both ruby and java:

To configure namespace in Jesque, use:

```
  val config = new ConfigBuilder().withNamespace("you_namespace").build()
```

To configure namespace in ruby, create sidekiq.rb inside `config/inititalizers` dir:

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :namespace => 'you_namespace' }
end
```